# Angular/NodeJs Webapp, JWT Auth or Session Auth?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, session, authentication, jwt

For a webapp which kind of Auth? Pros/Cons?

The app should be a webapp for FE we plan to use Angular, for BE we plan to use NodeJS.
The app will have public routes and private routes depending by role of user, and we plan to develop also an Android and iOS app too.

I see there are two approaches:

- JSON Web Token
- Session

I read some post that did not recommend the JWT instead of Session.

some consideration:

**JWT**

cons

- needs a server side check for invalidate some token (so the approach are not stateles)
- user information: if I put them inside the payload could generate an heavy headers and, if user information change (i.e. role) I need to change the token (and invalidate the previous). If I use only User ID inside Payload I have to load everytime from DB or cache system (i.e. Redis).

pro

- API with JWT Auth seems easy to be used via web or native mobile app

**Session** (i.e. Express Session with Redis)

cons

- session set a cookie with the session ID, it seems to be difficult to use this approach in mobile native app.

**Could you confirm or add other pros/cons and suggest the best approach?**

Using Socket.io (With server session/cache) instead REST API could be a valid alternative to the previous approaches?

Comment: I think you are looking for **role-based access control** (RBAC) and simply want to throw a 403 error

Comment: @AlekseySolovey sure, the will have a RBAC instead a user based, but the question is about the way to implement it, via JWB or Session.
in case of JWT I need to add role and capabilities inside the payload, or load it every time in sever side (in this case we lost the advantage of JWT).

Comment: You said "JWT needs a server side check for invalidate some token (so the approach are not stateles)". Checking user on the server does not cause the tokens to be stateful. It's rather the distinction of opaque and not-opaque tokens. As for the other differences - as always - depends on your case. Read some blog posts and other articles - there are plenty of them. Voting to close this question as Primarily opinion based.